# Forcing truediv with pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

In pandas, you can divide arrays either using the division operator `/` (which automatically does truediv) or by using the method `div()`. `div()` is useful because you can explicitly define the axis for the operation; unfortunately, it seems like it only performs integer division, rather than true division. I keep hitting up against this issue and it sucks to always need to multiply by `1.` or use `astype`.  Am I missing a method somewhere? There isn't a `truediv` method and I can't find anything online. (though `dir` reveals that it does define `__truediv__` and it supports truediv with the `/` operator.

```
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.arange(6)})
print df.A.div(df.A.sum()) # zeros
# print df.A.truediv(df.A.sum()) # no truediv method
print df.A / df.A.sum() # truedivision as expected
```

Assuming that I didn't miss a method and I need to use `div` so I can specify an axis, which is the preferred way to do this stylistically? (or, if applicable, which is more "pythonic"?)

Is it preferred to do:

```
df.A.div(df.A.sum() * 1.0)
```

or

```
df.A.astype(float).div(df.A.sum())
```

Does this change if the divisor is an array itself?

Comment: you can specify dtype in the constructor, e.g. ``pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.arange(6) }, dtype='float64')`` to force a float and then all div will be true (as an aside, I agree there should be a ``truediv`` method like ``div``, pls open an issue)

Comment: you can also do: ``df.A.__truediv__(df.A.sum())``, but only for axis=0

Comment: @Jeff I was thinking the same thing in terms of an issue. And you can definitely set dtype to `float64` but that doesn't resolve the issue when writing a function you want to reuse :)

Comment: true (pun intended); I would just astype to be sure, my 2c

Comment: @Jeff I'm in the process of writing a patch to add this to pandas. Hopefully the next version will have it.

Comment: Random aside - this question jumpstarted my entire career in software engineering (because it sucked me into contributing to pandas). Crazy to circle back 7 years later and realize I write code (sometimes even with pandas!) daily!